# Laravel mySql joins

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Hi im new to Laravel and im just trying to work out the query builder.

If i wanted to do this query :

```
SELECT *  
FROM product 
INNER JOIN price ON product.productid = price.productid 
LEFT JOIN purchaseitem ON product.productid = purchaseitem.productid 
WHERE product.name =  '.$keyword.'
```

Would i be on the right lines with something like this :

```
DB::table('product')
                    ->join('price','product.productid','=','price.productid')
                    ->leftJoin('purchaseitem','product.productid','=','purchaseitem.productid')
                    ->where('product.name','=','Superior King Room')->get();
```

I Cant really work out what the best way to do the inner join is. If anyone has any ideas it would be a big help.

Thanks.

Comment: your code is correct. what's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `->select('*')` and you are good to go. In the past I noticed how forgetting about it might lead to mistakes

```
DB::table('product')
    ->join('price','product.productid','=','price.productid')
    ->leftJoin('purchaseitem','product.productid','=','purchaseitem.productid')
    ->where('product.name','=','Superior King Room')
    ->select('*')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the DB::select() method:

```
\DB::select("SELECT *  
FROM product 
INNER JOIN price ON product.productid = price.productid 
LEFT JOIN purchaseitem ON product.productid = purchaseitem.productid 
WHERE product.name = ?", [$keyword]);
```

I like using this better than the query builder. This is gonna return an array of StdClasses, and all of the columns will be stored as properties on each of the StdClasses in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the joining issue and use the eloquent relationship.. It is pretty easy and simple rather than writing a very long query.

Here is the link

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: if possibly please provide a snippet of code that might help his specific answer

Comment: You can make a relationship between product and purchaseitem through product

Comment: That link explain everything